# View state mode of an inline VF page

Tags: visualforce, debugging, inline-visualforce, viewstate

I have a visual force page which I have embedded in a custom object page layout. I have the developer mode and view state enabled in my user setting. But when I go to the record where I have embedded my visual force page I do not see the developer mode footer in the bottom. How can I get the developer mode footer with view state and all.

Comment: Have you tried navigating to the page directly? (i.e. outside of the standard page) URL format is:  `/apex/<PageName>`

Comment: Yes, but I do not get any data in that. When go to view state the variables are empty.

Comment: Try `/apex/<PageName>?id=<OneRecordId>`

Comment: I'll add it as an answer, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried navigating to the page directly? (i.e. outside of the standard page).

URL format is: `/apex/<PageName>?id=<OneRecordId>`